# Can i compile pytorch to run on android platform using maui?

Tags: android, pytorch, maui

I have a question about: Can i compile pytorch to run on android platform using maui.
I know there are other solutions like moving the model from pytorch to onnx and running it on android or using pytorch mobile solution. I don't have much knowledge in this field.
That's why I'm asking if it's even possible ?

I tried to compile pytorch for ARM architecture, but I got several errors among others that it can't see the identifier _addcarry_u64.